# How to Link Up page in php mvc

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know, how to get linkup page in PHP MVC.

This is my link page, but it's not working.

My Link id is wrong...

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href='?Controller=Show_data&action=UserCreationView.php'>
        <img src="../../public/images/ModuleImages/Security.gif" style="height: 130px; width: 150px;"/>
    </a>
    <p style='color: #1b6d85; font-weight: bold;'>SECURITY</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the link doesn't work? You should also specify the file name before the question mark!

Comment: yes , link not work i tried this,

Comment: <a href='../Database/databaseConnection.php/Model/Model.php/Controller/Controller.php/Modules/Security/SubModules/Masters/UserCreationView.php?Controller=Show_data'><img src="../../public/images/ModuleImages/Security.gif" style="height: 130px; width: 150px;"/></a>

Comment: is there something wrong in this link because i got this error on page, The requested URL was not found on this server.